# Android Studio Navigation Draw Activity

Tags: android, background, navigation-drawer

I am creating an App with a Navigation Draw Activity.  In android studio, after I start a new android activity project, I select Navigation draw activity.  My question is, how to a change the background color of the navigation draw activity?  Right now, the top part is green but the white part where the text and icons are is white and I want to change this white part to dark grey with white text.

Thanks.
Rob

Comment: Please add layout file to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **res -> layout -> activity_main.xml** and add the following:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemTextColor="#A9A9A9"     // text color
        android:background="#FF0000" /> // background color
```

---

The top part it is defined in **res -> layout -> nav_header_main.xml** and the same color definitions apply to it too. Look for :

```
<LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar" />
```

and change it to any color you want.

Comment: Hi, This did change the background and text but now it looks like the original navigation drawer with a transparent sheet with the color I specified placed over the original.  The text is indeed white but I can see the original icons undenearth this layer.  So I can still see the icons in the background and the white.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some changes.

To define the color there are two ways to use the colors file in the values ​​directory or define in hexadecimal as for example android: background = "# 84FFFF".

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/ejemplo_nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/ejemplo_nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/ejemplo_drawer_view"
    android:background="@color/color_define"/>
```

Comment: Adding android:background= line doesn't work.  It makes it look like someone placed an opaque plastic sheet over it and I can see everything underneath.